# Laravel 5.2 returns error 500 with nothing to show

Tags: php, laravel, subdomain, laravel-5

I'm just about to host my laravel application. I use subdomains with wildcards. However I can somehow not access my auth and register views even though it works locally.

Route

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{slug}.mypage.de'], function()
{
    Route::controllers([
        'auth' => 'Auth\AuthControllerClient'
    ]);
    ...
```

I have the same route without the subdomain group where it works...

Comment: If you're getting a 500, then check the logs

Comment: cannot access them currently on the remote server....

Comment: do i need to configure subdomains somehwere else in the config files?

Comment: you need to set up error logging. Check this out: https://bugsnag.com/